# problem with get particular column value in array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a function to get the count of a particular title.

I have shown some elements of my array below

```
$arrayName = array('0' => array('page_title' => '10 Best Free VPS Hosting Sites 2019 (with Pros and Cons)', 'COUNT' => '465'), '1' => array('page_title' => 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)', 'COUNT' => '113'));
```

I want to get the `COUNT` of a particular page_title from this array. For that I have created the function below:

```
function particular_page_title_count($arrayName, $find_aff){
    foreach ($arrayNameas $row) {
        $affiliate = $row['page_title'];
        $count = $row['COUNT '];
        if ($affiliate == $find_aff) {
            return $count;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$particular_page_title_count = particular_page_title_count($arrayName, 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)');
echo $particular_page_title_count;
```

When I print the output of this function it shows me null even though the array has this page title in it.

I don't know why this happens can anybody help me with this.

Comment: You have some typo in your code :

- in foreach the `as` should be separate by a space
- You have a ` ` after the key `COUNT` that could cause some problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$count = $row['COUNT '];
```

you have an extra space after `COUNT`. Change it to

```
$count = $row['COUNT'];
```

and it works fine.

However there are many functions in PHP which can make writing this type of function easier. For example, you can use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find a title in the `page_title` column, and then use that key value to get the `COUNT`:

```
function particular_page_title_count($arrayName, $find_aff){
    if (($k = array_search($find_aff, array_column($arrayName, 'page_title'))) !== false) {
        return $arrayName[$k]['COUNT'];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
113
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RE16U)

Comment: @Mohini it will return 0 if the title doesn't exist in the original array. If you check my [demo](https://3v4l.org/RE16U), you can see that where the title exists in the array it returns the correct `COUNT` value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_column for the same,

```
$arrayName = array('0' => array('page_title' => '10 Best Free VPS Hosting Sites 2019 (with Pros and Cons)', 'COUNT' => '465'), '1' => array('page_title' => 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)', 'COUNT' => '113'));
$temp = array_column($arrayName, 'COUNT', 'page_title');
$particular_page_title_count = ($temp['Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)'] ?? '');
echo $particular_page_title_count;
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

**Note:-** **array_column()** returns the values from a single column of the **input**, identified by the **column_key**. Optionally, an **index_key** may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the **index_key** column of the input array.

I am considering you will have unique page titles.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Rp8MT)

**O/p**

```
113
```

Comment: This is also a good way to solve this. You might want to consider an `isset` (or null coalescing operator) to avoid undefined index errors.

Comment: As you said, mate. Have a look now.

Comment: @Rahul it shows me error: Undefined index: Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)

Comment: I shared demo link in my answer. You can check there right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your edited and working code execute it.

```
<?php

$arrayName = array('0' => array('page_title' => '10 Best Free VPS Hosting Sites 2019 (with Pros and Cons)', 'COUNT' => '465'), '1' => array('page_title' => 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)', 'COUNT' => '113'));


function particular_page_title_count($arrayName, $find_aff){
foreach ($arrayName as $row) {
    $affiliate = $row['page_title'];
    $count = $row['COUNT'];
    if ($affiliate == $find_aff) {
        return $count;
    }
}
return 0;
}


$particular_page_title_count = particular_page_title_count($arrayName, 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)');
echo $particular_page_title_count;

?>
```

Added space $arrayName and as removed space from $row['COUNT '] and it works. One suggestion dont use function name same as variable name. It gets difficult to handle.